# How to load a JS function via a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a function I want to load which is quite long, so I would like to save it to a variable and load the function through it.
I wrote something like this:

```
var check = function() {
do this...
and that...
}
```

Then, I have an onclick function, that will execute different commands along with this function, so I wrote:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
do this...
check;
and that...
});
```

But it won't load my function. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `check();` in your button onclick to call the function instead of `check;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the function by simply calling `check()`. Since not much code is shared , it is not clear whether any module system like AMD or common.js is used or not. In that case `this.functionName()` also works, provided the correct context of `this` is passed.

```js
function check() {
  alert('function called')
}

$('#btn').click(function() {
  check();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this function afterwords with `()` like `check()`.

Answer (score 0):

The actual way of calling a named function would be:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  do this...
  check();
  and that...
});
```